# Измерение количества уникальных объектов

Tags: powershell

Есть файл csv в котором всего один столбец - "Город для сайта". В столбце идут названия городов, причем не в каждой строке есть значение. Файл приблизительно выглядит так:

```
Москва
Киев

Париж
Киев
Осло

Токио
Токио
```

подскажите как получить приблизительно такой вывод:

```
Москва -1
Киев -2
Париж -1
Осло -1
Токио -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get-content 'E:\spam.txt' |` #Получаем данные из файла
Group-Object |` #Группируем данные
?{$_.name -ne ''} |` #Проверяем что имя не равно пустоте
select Name, Count #Выбираем имя и количество элементов
```

Ну а все вместе будет выглядеть так:

```
get-content 'E:\spam.csv' |  Group-Object | ?{$_.name -ne ''} | select Name, Count
```

Вывод:

```
Name   Count
----   -----
Москва     1
Киев       2
Париж      1
Осло       1
Токио      2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = Get-Content "data.txt" -Encoding UTF8 | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }
$data -Split [Environment]::NewLine | Group-Object | Select-Object -Property Name, Count
```

Укажите правильное имя файла и кодировку.

Comment: а в один pipe можно сложить? :)